# How to add two numbers?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JavaScript calculator... but suppose when I give my first number as `2` and the second number as `3`, the result is showing `23`, but I wanted to add the two numbers.

Can anyone please help me? It is also happening when I try to minus the two numbers. Why isn't this working?

```
var cal = prompt("Please enter what type of calculation you want to do\n
if you wanna add enter = 1\n
if you want to minus enter = 2\n
if you want to divide enter = 3\n
if you want to multiply enter = 4");

if (cal == 1) {
    var a = prompt("Please enter your first number");
    var b = prompt("please enter your second number");

    alert("The result is , " + a+b);
}

if (cal == 2) {
    var c = prompt("Please enter your first number");
    var d = prompt("please enter your second number");

    alert("the result is , " + c - d);
}
```

Comment: use `parseInt()` to convert them to integer value

Comment: You may also want to note that cal == 1 and cal == 2 works because when using double equals it attempts a conversion, where as when you use triple equals it matches the type as well (whether they are both numbers and both the same value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cal = prompt("Please enter what type of calculation you want to do\n" +
  "if you want to add enter = 1\n" +
  "if you want to minus enter = 2\n" +
  "if you want to divide enter = 3\n" +
  "if you want to multiply enter = 4");

if (cal == 1) {
    var a = prompt("Please enter your first number");
    var b = prompt("please enter your second number");

    alert("The result is , " + (Number(a) + Number(b)));
}

else if (cal == 2) {
    var c = prompt("Please enter your first number");
    var d = prompt("please enter your second number");

    alert("the result is , " + (Number(c) - Number(d)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` sign is used to concatenate strings together, not to add them together mathematically.

You need to wrap your variables in `parseInt()`, e.g.

```
alert("The result is , " + parseInt(a)+parseInt(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert a string to a number after you accept it from user:

```
a = parseInt(a, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prompts return strings, you need to parse them as integers (you could also do floats using `parseFloat`)

`alert("The result is , " + (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)));`

Answer (score 1):

The `Prompt` method returns the entered value as a string.

So after `Prompt` use `parseInt()`, this function parses a string and returns an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The **binary** [`+` operator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators#Arithmetic_Operators) has two uses: addition and string concatenation. Although you want the former, the latter is happening because [`window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt) returns a string.

To avoid this, you should do one of the following (read the documentation so you can understand the differences):

- Parse the strings as integers using [`parseInt(str, 10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- Parse the strings as floating-point numbers using [`parseFloat(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- Cast the strings to numbers using the **unary** plus operator: [`+str`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29).
- Alternatively, [`Number(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) can be used.

It is wise to check whether the numbers could be parsed (using [`isNaN(num)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), or possibly `num === num`) before trying to perform calculations with them, so your script can show a helpful error message instead of just carrying `NaN` through to its output.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to Strings; known as concatenation, you need to [convert the String representations to numbers](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm) then add them.

```
alert("The result is , " + (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
alert("The result is , " + (parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because var is dynamic type variable, so your variable translated as string.

Please note that function can receive double, so `parseInt` may not work correctly

```
function Add(a,b)
{
   var result = null;

   if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b))
   {
      alert("Please send the number");
      return;
   }

   a = Number(a);
   b= Number(b);

   return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var add = parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = window.prompt("Please Enter Your Num1 :");
num2 = window.prompt("Please Enter Your Num2 :");
var sum = parseInt(num1)+ parseInt(num2);
document.writeln("<h1> The summ of two integers,"+num1+", and,"+num2+", is ,"+sum+",</h1>"  )
```

I Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let num1 = prompt("Enter the first interger number..");
let num2 = prompt("Enter the second float number...");

let sum = (Number(num1) + Number(num2));
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).