# arithmetic operation + just combines both the variables

Tags: java

this program gives the output by merging n1 and n2 but I want that both to be arithmetically added

```
String answer = "";

    if (a1.equals("+")){
        answer = (n1 + n2);
    }
    else if (a1.equals("-")){
        answer = n1 + n2;
    }
```

Comment: You need to convert to a number first.

Comment: Don't you mean `n1 - n2` for `"-"` ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey He probably left it at + since - gives compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String addition (that means + when one or more of the sides are strings), will always try concatenate the inputs instead of adding them. To make an arithmetic addition both inputs need to be `Number` types, that means int, double, float, char.

Use `int number1 = Integer.parseInt(n1)` and `int number2 = Integer.parseInt(n2)` and then use the `+` operator on the int's, not on strings.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to start with to initialize as numeric

```
var answer = 0;
var n1 = 0;
var n2 = 0;
```

OR

Use parseInt for your numeric variables n1, and n2

Check this post:

[How to add two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292523/how-to-add-two-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is going on here - either n1 and n2 are both strings in which case you need to use Integer.parseInt() around them.

Or because you are adding them to something that is already a String because you have set initialized the  empty String above they are being coerced to Strings before being added.  In which case you could initalise to null or perform the calculation in a seperate variable first.

Comment: Since he put parenthesis around the addition, the second scenario is unlikely. They should ignore what they're assigned to until the parenthesis has been solved.